# Meaning of Ruby "===" operator on Ranges

Tags: ruby, operators, range

I recently started learning Ruby and i'm reading the following [Ruby Manual](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/).

In this manual they say the following (about Ranges):

> A final use of the versatile range is as an interval test: seeing if
>   some value falls within the interval represented by the range. This is
>   done using ===, the case equality operator.

With these examples:

- (1..10)    === 5 »   true
- (1..10)    === 15    »   false
- (1..10)    === 3.14159   »   true
- ('a'..'j') === 'c'   »   true
- ('a'..'j') === 'z'   »   false

After read about the Ruby "===" operator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154876/ruby-comparison-operators-vs), I found that this works on ranges because Ruby translates this to case statement.

> So you may want to be able to put the range in your case statement,
>   and have it be selected. Also, note that case statements translate to
>   b===a in statements like case a when b then true end.

However I have the following question: why does the following command return true?

(1..10)    === 3.14159  »   true

Since (1..10) means [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], I expected that the result would be false.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1..10` indicates a [`Range`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html) from 0 to 10 in the mathematical sense and hence contains `3.14259`

It is *not* the same as `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

This array is a consequence of the method [`Range#each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html#method-i-each), used by [`Enumerable#to_a`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) to construct the array representation of an object, yielding only the integer values included
in the Range, since yielding all real values would mean traversing an infinite number of elements.